Google Cloud Function Shows ETIMEOUT Error When Connected To VPC Connector
I have deployed a GCP Cloud Function to make calls to Adobe APIs. Also, the same Cloud Function is making calls to Jira APIs. The Jira platform requires API calls to happen only through static IP address. Hence, I have configured a VPC Connector with my Cloud Function.
When I run this Cloud Function, I get below error.

Error: request to https://reactor.adobe.io/rules/RL*******************123/rule_components failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 12.123.123.123:443

Below are my settings for ingress and egress traffic in Cloud Function.
Ingress settings: Allow all traffic
Egress settings: Route all traffic through the VPC connector

How to get rid of ETIMEOUT error while still using the VPC connector?
Please note that I am using Static IP, Cloud Router, Cloud NAT and Firewall. Let me know if any more details are needed.

From the best of my understanding (unless things changed in GCP), VPC connector will route traffic into a VPC network... So, I assume a static IP address is allocated, Cloud Router and Cloud NAT are created, am I right?

Hi @al-dann You are right. A static IP address is allocated, Cloud Router, Cloud NAT and Firewall are also used. It will be great if you can help resolve the issue. Also, let me know if you need more details.

can use create a 'test' compute engine machine inside the VPN, and check if the connection to your third party service provider can be established? - that should go through that dedicated IP address.

Regarding the error message, mostly it was focused on a firewall problem. Sharing with you these link1, link2, link3, link4 and link5 that has the same error with different scenario that concentrated on resolving this on firewall.
To diagnose this concern, we need to use some of the tools to check what might be causing this issue. From your firewall, double check the created firewall rule to make sure that you use the right IP ranges, ports, protocol and the right VPC network. Most common mistake on this configuration is the VPC network. Make sure that the firewall rule targets the right VPC network.
Other suggestions to diagnose this concern is the use of Logs. You can enable the VPC Flow Logs run and test the traffic then check the logs. You can also use Connectivity test wherein you can place the source and the destination of the traffic and monitor where the packet will drop.
Check also the network from the client side, network connection works both ways. Since ETIMEDOUT is the error message, I suggest checking the firewall or any security from the other side.

Thanks for your answer. My issue is more related to the link1 you have shared. Likely, there's an issue in my VPC connector, Cloud Router or Cloud NAT. I am still figuring out the problem.
